# Javafx Changing Spesific Row Color by Database Value

Tags: javafx, tableview

I select a row in my tableview and then click button panggilAntrian. When I click that button, boolean_antri is true and I want to the color of row is change to green.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Antrian> antrianTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, Integer> id;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, String> tanggal;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, Integer> no_antrian;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, String> jam_ambil;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, String> jam_panggil;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Antrian, Boolean> boolean_antrian;

@FXML
    private void actionPanggilAntrian(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date time = new Date();
        String waktuPanggil = timeFormat.format(time);

        int id = antrian.getId();
        boolean boolean_antri = false;

        String sql = "UPDATE antrian SET jam_panggil = '" + waktuPanggil + "', boolean_antrian = true where id = '" + id + "'";

        try (Connection conn = connection.connection();
             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)
            ){  
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                boolean_antri = true;
                antrian.setId(id);
                antrian.setBooleanAntrian(boolean_antri);
                txtNoDipanggil.setText(Integer.toString(idAntrian));

                    boolean_antrian.setCellFactory(col -> { //There's an error: java.lang.NullPointerException in boolean_antrian
                        TableCell<Antrian, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<Antrian, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (item) {
                                    TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();
                                    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    });
            } catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
```

There's an error:
java.lang.NullPointerException in boolean_antrian.setCellFactory.
The value of boolean_antrian is null.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The `TableColumn` `boolean_antrian` (please learn the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)) has not yet been initialized when you call your `actionPanggilAntrian()` method. A simple [mcve] would help here.

Comment: Three things: (1) This will set the cell factory of the table column each time the `actionPanggilAntrian` method is invoked. Setting the cell factory should only happen once, during initialization. (2) You never reset/change the color when the cell's item is null or false or when the cell is empty. This will leave you with green cells that shouldn't be green. (3) We need a [mre] to properly diagnose the problem; please [edit] your question to provide one.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: related: creating a tableRow in the updateItem of a tableCell is ... utter nonsense (no offense meant but that's sooo wrong that it needs strong wording, IMO). Time to read a basic tutorial on cells and how/when they are created and used, the info page of the javafx tag has references. And best to start with a simple example and adjust it step by step to your requirements ... changing the styles of cells based on content is not overly difficult, but needs a clear understanding of which cell is responsible for what - there are tons of examples on this site and elsewhere